# await + ConfigureAwait()

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Коллеги, добрый день. Прошу помощи с ConfigureAwait().

**Мои знания на таком уровне**: это метод, который указывает среде выполнения, что при возвращении из асинхронного метода (запущенного в другом потоке) не нужно пользоваться контекстом синхронизации. Т.е. не ждать пока освободится поток, в котором началось выполнение кода (до await), а продолжать выполнение кода (который после await) в том же потоке, в каком выполнялся сам асинхронный таск (сам await).
Это повышает производительность, однако стоит использовать с осторожностью в задачах где присутствуют UI потоки (WPF, ASP.NET). **Поправьте пожалуйста, если я не прав.**

И дальше возникает второй вопрос. Допустим у меня есть такая цепочка асинхронных вызовов:

```
    public async Task M1()
    {
        return await M2();
    }

    public async Task M2()
    {
        return await M3();
    }

    public async Task M3()
    {
        return await 
             dbContext.Users
                   .ToListAsync()
                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

В методе M3() происходит асинхронное ожидание. EF создает новый поток и читает из БД, мы ждем. Все ок.

А что происходит в M2()? Создается ли новый поток для выполнения таска `await M3()`. Аналогичный вопрос для метода M1(). Стоит ли в этих await-ах использовать ConfigureAwait(false), либо достаточно того, что мы использовали этот метод в M3()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите.

`ConfigureAwait(false)` действует напрямую только на `await`, который ожидает данный Task (точнее, данный *tasklike*). Это означает, что во внешней функции будет обычным образом захвачен контекст, и выполнение вернётся туда по окончанию `await`. То, в каком или в каких контекстах пробегает код `M1`, не играет роли, если `M2` бежит в синхронизационном контексте.

Comment: получается в моем случае (учитывая, что тут нет UI операций) стоит добавить ConfigureAwait(false) ко всей цепочке асинхронных ожиданий?

Comment: @nikita: Да. В библиотечном коде имеет смысл использовать `ConfigureAwait(false)` практически везде. (Хотя обычно лень.)

Comment: @nikita: Исключение — если ваш библиотечный код использует глобальные переменные, нужно быть более осторожным, чтобы не создать нечаянно race condition. В этом случае вам, наверное, нужен собственный синхронизационный контекст для библиотеки. Но лучше быть «функциональным» и использовать только локальные переменные, тогда проблем не возникает.

Comment: по вашему опыту, имеет ли смысл делать каждый вызов к EF в приложении асинхронным? или не стоит городить огород и оборачивать в асинхронность только по умолчанию долгие  и тяжелые запросы?

Comment: @nikita: Обычно, если запрос тяжёлый, я не даю ему бежать в текущем контексте (потому что это может случайно оказаться UI-контекст), а есть ли по дороге `ConfigureAwait(false)`, не так уж и критично. В наихудшем случае просто после каждого `await` будет происходить ненужное возвращение в исходный контекст. Но в любом случае, тяжёлые операции никогда не должны бежать в случайном, непредсказуемом контексте, только это обычно реально важно.

Comment: я делаю вывод, что не стоит обвешивать асинхронностью каждый запрос к БД (поиск по первичному ключу, выборка справочника на 100 записей) -  это ненужные заморочки и на асинхронность в таких случаях проще забить?

Comment: @nikita: Ну, забить полностью не удастся, вы ж не можете тормозить UI-поток? С другой стороны, вы должны сами спланировать, предоставляет ли ваша модель (база данных — это же модель, да?) синхронный интерфейс, то что вызывающий код должен делать сам `Task.Run`, или асинхронный интерфейс. Для нового EF, лучше асинхронный, т. к. он предоставляет сам асинхронные функции (например, `ToListAsync()`), которые **не требуют потока из пула** и вообще эффективнее.

Comment: @nikita: Если вы пойдёте по асинхронному варианту, то вам всё равно придётся протягивать `Task` как возвращаемый тип везде. А вот по поводу того, где и как часто использовать `ConfigureAwait(false)`, думаю, имеет смысл так делать только для улучшения производительности.